# Add style on parent element of multiple set of radio buttons when checked without using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem of converting jquery code to javascript. 
Theres a set of radio buttons and i need to add a style on its parent element just like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/wCNAp/3/).

Every selection of each set of radio buttons a style will be added to its parent. I need to work it using only Javascript.

Here's the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/venz/a4vsawj6/1/): The effect should be similar to that first link.

i.e.

```
<ul>
    <li class="check"><label for="one">1<input type="radio" id="one" name="test"/></label>     
    </li>
    <li class="check"><label for="two">2<input type="radio" id="two" name="test"/></label>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="check"><label for="one">1<input type="radio" id="one" name="test2"/></label>
    </li>
    <li class="check"><label for="two">2<input type="radio" id="two" name="test2"/></label>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="check"><label for="one">1<input type="radio" id="one" name="test3"/></label>
    </li>
    <li class="check"><label for="two">2<input type="radio" id="two" name="test3"/></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code provides the expected functionality without jQuery:

```
function changeEvent(event) {
    //add highlight class
    this.parentNode.classList.add("highlight");
    try {
        //remove highlight class from previously selected radio in group
        //if already existing
        this.parentNode.parentNode.highlightDIV.classList.remove("highlight");
    } catch (ignore) {}
    //keep the highlighted div as a property of the parent div
    this.parentNode.parentNode.highlightDIV = this.parentNode;
}

//select all radio buttons
var radioList = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
//loop through list and add event listener
for (var i = 0; i < radioList.length; i++) {
    radioList[i].addEventListener("change", changeEvent, false);
}
```

It uses references to `parentNode` but they can be replaced by algorithms to dynamically find the wanted nodes in a more dynamic structure.
I hope you get the direction and you may improve and modify the code to fit into your applications needs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ..i tested your code and it does highlight the parent element but everytime you click to the other radio button it will highlight also..here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/venz/a4vsawj6/ .

Comment: can you make it similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/wCNAp/3/ . please... but it should be javascript

Comment: In your second version the `input` fields are children of `label` elements. It works when you use my suggestion with your first version - just replace the jQuery code with my code.

Comment: Your second example contains another big problem: You're using multiple labels referring the same ID and your IDs are not unique!

Comment: why is it the code is not working in IE8? It says parentNode is null or not an object.

Comment: Do you use exactly the same code or you did some modifications? Please provide a fiddle and I may help you out.

Comment: I did some modifications. Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/venz/1ba0m6nz/ . It seems that parentNode is not working in IE8 properly.

Comment: I'm not able to test on IE 8 on my actual location. But it may be possible that the reference for `this` is not correct. Try this and tell me if it works: http://jsfiddle.net/1ba0m6nz/2/

Comment: For improved handling and controlling `this` please use: http://jsfiddle.net/1ba0m6nz/3/

Comment: I tested it again in IE8 but still it doesn't work properly. It has the same error, it says "Message: 'this.parentNode.classList' is null or not an object"

Comment: Well, that's a DIFFERENT error and it's true that IE 8 does not support the `classList` property. You have to use the property `className` in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/1ba0m6nz/4/ - It may cause problems later if you want to add more classes. In this case you would have to implement your own `addClass` and `removeClass` functions.